# Setting EPSON XP-342 printer on Arch linux

Tags: drivers, printer

I am running Arch Linux with Gnome and I am unable to set up my EPSON XP-342 printer.
I have cups installed and enabled. I installed epson-inkjet-printer-escpr from the AUR. I also installed foomatic-db-engine, foomatic-db, foomatic-db-ppds, gutenprint and foomatic-db-gutenprint-ppds.
When I try to add a printer via the settings, I can find my printer but when I add it I get: failed to add printer and a message stating additional printer drivers required.

Kindly advise what am I missing.

Comment: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/03/28/printer-epson-xp-342-xp-343-xp-345-arch-linux-installation-step-by-step/

Comment: Thank you but this tutorial doesnt help. You can see from my question, I already installed what the tutorial suggests.